# Can I connect a DisplayPort monitor to the Thunderbolt port on a Mac, and vice-versa?

Tags: mac, display, displayport, thunderbolt

Does anyone know if a monitor equipped with a DisplayPort (e.g. the [Dell U2311h](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=320-9270) LCD screen) can be connected to the Thunderbolt port on a Mac?

I want to connect two of these LCDs (one via Thunderbolt, the other via HDMI) to my Mac Mini 2011 and am wondering what my options are.

Vice-versa, can I connect a Thunderbolt display to a Mac with a Mini DisplayPort?

**Update:** What is the compatibility like for Thunderbolt 3 and USB-C DP Alt mode?

It is possible to connect USB-C DP Alt mode monitors to thunderbolt 3 hosts. But is it possible to connect thunderbolt monitors (ones that don't explicitly advertise DP alt mode support) to USB-C DP Alt mode hosts?

Comment: Thunderbolt is backwards compatible with display port, so yes.

Comment: In my experience the cable type is important here too, see the "compatibility" diagram in the post by @ErikKaju in [Is there a difference between “Thunderbolt” and “Mini DisplayPort” cables?](http://superuser.com/questions/866870/is-there-a-difference-between-thunderbolt-and-mini-displayport-cables).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### Connect a DisplayPort display to Thunderbolt port

As Apple says on [their Thunderbolt product page](http://www.apple.com/thunderbolt/):

> And because Thunderbolt is based on DisplayPort technology, the video standard for high-resolution displays, **any Mini DisplayPort display plugs right into the Thunderbolt port**. To connect a DisplayPort, DVI, HDMI, or VGA display, just use an existing adapter.

To confirm this, here's [what Intel says](http://www.intel.com/technology/io/thunderbolt/index.htm):

> And **Thunderbolt enabled products are compatible with existing DisplayPort devices** so you don’t have to go buy a new display to take advantage of a Thunderbolt technology enabled computer.

<sub>... emphasis mine.</sub>

This means that you can attach your DisplayPort-equipped monitor to any Mac with a Thunderbolt plug. If your display has DisplayPort only (i.e. *not* Mini DisplayPort), you will of course need an adapter to do this.

For the other display, just use the HDMI connection. You could also daisy-chain two displays together, if these displays support it and have two DisplayPorts each.

---

#### Connect a Thunderbolt display to (Mini) DisplayPort

The opposite seems to be possible, as the physical connection is the same. However, Apple states differently. Their [tech specs](http://www.apple.com/displays/specs.html) don't mention the Mac Pro being capable of using it. The problem will be that you can't update the display's firmware and use the data pipe.

So, all in all, **it won't work**.

Ars Technica has [a recent article about this](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/09/apples-thunderbolt-display-doesnt-play-nice-with-mini-displayport.ars), which states that there *might* be issues:

> What is really going to rub folks the wrong way, we suspect, is that the Thunderbolt Display is not configured to work with a miniDP display plugged in to its Thunderbolt port. It wouldn't be surprising if more than one user with an existing 27" Cinema Display or other miniDP display got a Thunderbolt-equipped Mac and ordered a Thunderbolt display expecting to be able to add the miniDP display at the end of the chain.

Comment: Thank you very much slhck, that answers my question. I wasn't aware of Apple's general TB page. Unfortunately I now realize that this Dell LCD does not have an HDMI port. :| Back to looking for an LCD that can handle both.

Comment: Oh, that is unfortunate. I don't know if there are that many of those. You can buy a Thunderbolt to DVI adapter though! By the way, if it answered your question, you can click the checkmark to the left of it to mark it as such!

Comment: You definitely cannot connect a DisplayPort (but not Thunderbolt) equipped Macs to a Thunderbolt display.  I've tried this, and it does not work.  (However, a Thunderbolt Mac will connect to a DisplayPort display.)

Comment: @MichaelStillwell Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 4):

Apple's just released a support document about their Thunderbolt-based displays here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4885

Note this bit:

> Mini DisplayPort displays will not light up if connected to the Thunderbolt port on an Apple Thunderbolt Display (27-inch).

So there will be no daisy-chaining MDP and TB-based displays from the looks of it.