# Connecting external screen to a 2007 MacBook with DVI

Tags: mac, dvi, external-display

I would like to buy an external monitor to connect to my MacBook in order to work in an easier and more efficient way in iPhoto.

I understood I need a DVI cable (only 19€ in the Apple Store). But do I need to buy a screen from Apple or can any screen be connected to the MacBook?

Answer (score 2):

If your MacBook has a normal [DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) connector (the MacBook Pro models had one), you can connect any monitor with a DVI input to it, regardless of its brand.

[image]

In general, Apple computers work with all kinds of monitors, not just those from Apple – given the right connector. Note that if your MacBook (white plastic one) uses a Mini-DVI connector, you'll need an adapter or cable from Mini-DVI → DVI to hook it up to the display.

For example, if your MacBook looks like this:

[image]

You need a Mini-DVI to DVI converter:

[image]

---

You'd only run into compatibility issues if the MacBook uses the new Thunderbolt connector and the display "just" uses Mini DisplayPort. This does not apply to your case, but for those interested, see here for more info: [Can I connect a DisplayPort monitor to the Thunderbolt port on a Mac, and vice-versa?](https://superuser.com/questions/333442/can-i-connect-a-displayport-monitor-to-the-thunderbolt-port-ona-mac-and-vice-v)